# Name of the following property for matrix multiplication.

Tags: matrices

${\bf Property}$: Let $A$ and $B$ two matrices such that $AB=\alpha I$, where alpha is a real number and $I$ is the identity matrix.

Somebody know what is the name of this property? Is there some reference about that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field and let $A$ be a square matrix over $\mathbb{F}$. Then $A$ is called a *scalar matrix* if and only if $A = \lambda I$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{F}$.

See also, say Friedberg's linear algebra.